# Brightness controls not working after BIOS update

Tags: debian, bios, thinkpad

I am running Debian Jessie on my Thinkpad X220. Yesterday, after flashing a new BIOS on the laptop, the brightness keys stopped working on Debian. I can change the brightness during the BIOS bootup though.

Sounds kinda strange to me. Any ideas?

#### update

It looks like the brightness controls are disabled by default. Here is the relevant output from `dmesg`

```
[    2.016833] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <thinkpad-x220>.
[    2.192092] thinkpad_acpi: ThinkPad ACPI Extras v0.25
[    2.192171] thinkpad_acpi: http://ibm-acpi.sf.net/
[    2.192258] thinkpad_acpi: ThinkPad BIOS 8DET69WW (1.39 ), EC unknown
[    2.192331] thinkpad_acpi: Lenovo ThinkPad X220, model 4291Y3H
[    2.193207] thinkpad_acpi: detected a 16-level brightness capable ThinkPad
[    2.200276] thinkpad_acpi: radio switch found; radios are enabled
[    2.200401] thinkpad_acpi: possible tablet mode switch found; ThinkPad in laptop mode
[    2.200496] thinkpad_acpi: This ThinkPad has standard ACPI backlight brightness control, supported by the ACPI video driver
[    2.200496] thinkpad_acpi: Disabling thinkpad-acpi brightness events by default...
[    2.202578] thinkpad_acpi: rfkill switch tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: radio is unblocked
[    2.203332] thinkpad_acpi: Standard ACPI backlight interface available, not loading native one
[    2.203637] thinkpad_acpi: Console audio control enabled, mode: monitor (read only)
[    2.205397] input: ThinkPad Extra Buttons as /devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/input/input5
[    2.305667] thinkpad_ec: thinkpad_ec 0.41 loaded.
```

Comment: As a temporary workaround, I am writing to the `/etc/power/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` file.

Comment: Do you mean `/sys/...`? Otherwise, check that the `thinkpad_acpi` module still loads, looks for messages in `dmesg` and possibly try various `brightness_mode` settings as described in the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/laptops/thinkpad-acpi.txt).

Comment: Thanks for the `dmesg` tip. I see more information related to the brightness settings, I updated the question accordingly. And yes, I meant to write `sys` instead of `etc` :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are quite a few solutions for the problem. The one that worked for me is via the `xbacklight` tool. I was able to map the `XF86_Brightness*` keys to the command in my window manager (DWM).

While its not perfect. It gets the job done.

Comment: Don't the names of the XF86_Brightness* buttons depend on the hardware? How did you find the right names?

Comment: I used the tool `xev` to look at the name-mappings for different keys on my keyboard.

Comment: Ah,ok. Sadly xev doesn't show me anything when I hit the combination of buttons for brightness control... My machine is Asus g56jr (for documenting purposes).

Comment: Nice. I have an old g51jx running arch. Unless I am wrong, I had to install a xorg package that came with the keysym.h which has all the mappings. 

A quick hack would be to look at the hex representation of the key using `xev` and hard-code it.